# Correct number for each item in will_paginate list?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, pagination, will-paginate

I'm using the will_paginate gem in my Rails app and loop through an array of model instances which are rendered on the page and limited to 5 per page. Before I added will_paginate I numbered each item with a simple <% i += 1 %> which of course went +1 with each loop through the array, and worked fine.

But now that I'm using will_paginate the count restarts on each page, so page 1 items go 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and then on the second page it starts over... 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Obviously this isn't ideal. How do I get the count to continue as you go to previous pages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `will_paginate` `Collection` is not just a simple `Array` or `ActiveRecord::Relation`. Instead it has some [additional methods](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/master/lib/will_paginate/collection.rb) defined, for example: `current_page`, `per_page`, `offset`, `total_entries` or `total_pages`.

You can use `Collection#offset` to calculate your current index:

```
<% @collection.each_with_index do |item, index| %>
  <%= @collection.offset + index + 1 %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

What can be simplified by initializing `Enumerator#with_index` with the first index (note the `.` between `each` and `with_index`:

```
<% @collection.each.with_index(@collection.offset + 1) do |item, index| %>
  <%= index %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for simple solution :)